# how to check stdin in C# while doing something

Tags: c#, concurrency, stdin

I have a program like this:

```
Class a
{
    main()
    {
        while(abc)
        {
            f(a);
            g(b);
        }
    }
}
```

but I need to check stdin for some important command. The programm should work will I receive a command from stdin. and after the command I should decide to continue execution or doing something else.
What should I do?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the program is already running (instead of starting) and you need to accept a command from the user while it is running. Is this correct and if so: Does your program pause to accept input from the Console to allow the user to enter the command, or is your program running as a Windows service, does is run multiple threads, or is it a different scenario?

Comment: Yes it is running. But opening two threads will destroy my program I need something like interupt. I need my cpu time so something like two thread will destroy my running program

Comment: What do you mean by *destroy your program*? Sometimes, when you need your code to do something it can't currently do, you may have to change a lot of code you wrote previously!

Comment: A low priority thread won't "destroy your running program" and will be quick enough for a human user to interact with. Threads won't destroy your program, and if there's any other process running on the computer (and there are) they are using your CPU too. Interesting scenario though.

Comment: I know. Using the maximum cpu time is very important in my programm. So I need something like an inpterrupt.

Comment: No, you need to use a thread :) Just set a low `ThreadPriority` on it and you're done.

Comment: And it won't take a lot of cpu time?

Comment: It wouldn't take "a lot of CPU time" from your "critical" processing unless you gave it higher than normal thread priority.

Answer (score 2):

Execute `f` and `g` in different threads with some sort of variable accessed by both to propagate the state change.

```
Class Program
{
  public static void Main()
  {
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => f(a));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(() => g(b));

    while(true)
    {
      if(Console.Readline() == "something")
        //do something
    }
  }

  private static void f (param)
  {
    while(abc)
      //do work
  }
}
```

Comment: Using something like threads will give lots of cpu time. I need all my cpu time for running my functions. I think something like an interrupt will work.. But I don't know how?

Comment: CPU time is the scheduler's concern, not yours. You can set a `ThreadPriorty`, you know that right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.priority.aspx

Comment: @Masoud: threads don't add a lot of overhead.  I can't possibly imagine that you are doing anything that actually requires so much CPU time that thread overhead is too costly, yet you don't understand how threads, interrupts, etc. work.

Comment: @Masoud - The main thread will actually be *blocked* until the user presses ENTER inside the ReadLine() method. A volatile boolean may be used to signal the end of execution. Put those two things together, and it is a good bet the threading overhead should be completely negligable with this method.

Answer (score 1):

This will work if your commands are single characters.

```
Class a
{
    main()
    {
        bool done = false;
        Console.CancelKeyPress += (s, e) => { done = true; e.Cancel = true; };
        while(!done)
        {
            f(a);
            g(b);
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                switch(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar)
                {
                    case 'i':
                    case 'I':
                        DoSomethingImportant();
                        break;
                    case 'E':
                    case 'e':
                        done = true;
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If the commands are longer than a single character, then you could store the keys in a buffer and look for completed commands at each keystroke.

There are other, more complicated, solutions involving threading, but if you don’t need to go that direction, then you shouldn’t.

(I added the CTRL-C handling in the above code, so it will exit cleanly if the user tries to stop the program. That part is optional.)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would need another Thread started before the while loop, which can take commands from the stdin.

Comment: I can't use a thread. Because I need my cpu time. I need something like an interrupt.

Comment: @Masoud A second thread will consume CPU time that is negligible. Especially when you wait for an input the thread will in fact wait for an interrupt without consuming CPU time.